# ERROR - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g, ora-00907

I am new to SQL and i got an error "ERROR - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" when i try to run my query, Please do help me out in solving this problem,Please do find the query below
Thanks in advance!

```
(SELECT
        DISTINCT d.order_key ord,
        d.order_status stat,
        m.order_call_key,
        m.opr_no opr_no,
        m.opr_step_no opr_step_no 
    FROM
        owi_order d,
        order_call m 
    WHERE
        d.rev_status = 'Complete' 
        AND d.order_type_cd <> 'ADPPO' 
        AND UPPER(d.pgm_id) = UPPER ('777') 
        AND (UPPER(m.init_callbrd_action_cd) IN ('MGWP', 'QWIP', 'RFI', 'RIOT', 'RIPI', 'RIR', 'RJSS', 'RNCR', 'RQAI', 'RSIR', 'RTQA') 
        OR (UPPER(m.cmpl_callbrd_action_cd) IN ('MGWP', 'QWIP', 'RFI', 'RIOT', 'RIPI', 'RIR', 'RJSS', 'RNCR', 'RQAI', 'RSIR', 'RTQA') 
        OR EXISTS  ( SELECT
            'x' 
        from
            order_call_ack a 
        where
            a.order_call_key=m.order_call_key 
            AND UPPER(a.ackd_callbrd_action_cd) IN ('MGWP', 'QWIP', 'RFI', 'RIOT', 'RIPI', 'RIR', 'RJSS', 'RNCR', 'RQAI', 'RSIR', 'RTQA') 
            AND a.active_ind <> 'N')) 
        and m.order_key = d.order_key), related_query AS ((SELECT
            s.related_order_key ord,
            s.order_key parent,
            b.order_call_key call_parent,
            o.order_call_key call 
        FROM
            related_obj s,
            owi_rep_query b,
            owi_order t,
            order_call o 
        WHERE
            s.order_key=b.ord 
            AND s.related_order_key = o.order_key 
            AND b.stat  IN ('Enqueued','Scheduled','Pulled') 
            AND s.related_obj_stat_cd <> 'DL' 
            AND s.related_order_key = t.order_key 
            AND t.rev_status IN ('Complete')  
            AND b.order_call_key <> o.order_call_key 
        UNION
        SELECT
            ord,
            to_number(null) parent,
            to_number(null) call_parent,
            order_call_key call 
        from
            owi_rep_query)), related_call_query AS (SELECT
        distinct ord,
        parent,
        MAX(call_parent) call_parent,
        call,
        (SELECT
            CASE m.call_status_nm  
                WHEN 'Completed' THEN m.cmpl_callbrd_action_cd 
                ELSE (SELECT
                    DISTINCT ackd_callbrd_action_cd 
                FROM
                    order_call_ack ock,
                    order_call ocaa 
                WHERE
                    ock.order_call_key = r.call 
                    AND ocaa.order_call_key = r.call 
                    AND ocaa.call_status_nm <> 'Completed' 
                    AND ock.ack_ts = (SELECT
                        MAX(ack_ts) 
                    FROM
                        order_call_ack t 
                    WHERE
                        t.order_call_key = ocaa.order_call_key 
                        AND t.active_ind <> 'N')) 
                END 
            FROM
                Order_call m 
            WHERE
                m.order_call_key = r.call) call_action 
        FROM
            related_query r 
        GROUP BY
            ord,
            parent,
            call),
            temp_rslt AS (SELECT
                RPAD(d.order_id,
                32,
                ' ') orderRecordIdTemp,
                TRIM(RPAD(m.acc_cd,
                3,
                ' '))||'/'||TRIM(RPAD(m.acc_pos_cd,
                3,
                ' '))||'/'|| RPAD(DECODE(m.work_loc_cd,
                '..',
                '',
                '...',
                '',
                m.work_loc_cd),
                3,
                ' ') accPosWl,
                LPAD(m.line_no,
                5,
                0) lineNumber,
                RPAD(m.call_id,
                8,
                ' ') callIdVal,
                RPAD(m.order_hld_ind,
                4,
                ' ') orderHldInd,
                RPAD(m.prty_no,
                4,
                ' ') prtyNo,
                RPAD(TO_CHAR(m.call_init_ts,
                'MM/DD HH24:MI'),
                11,
                ' ') callInitTs,
                RPAD(call_action,
                4,
                ' ') callAction,
                RPAD(TO_CHAR(m.ecd,
                'MM/DD HH24:MI'),
                11,
                ' ') ecdVal,
                RPAD(F_SUBPIPES(SUBSTR(REPLACE(NVL(m.remark_txt,
                TO_CLOB(' ')),
                '',
                ' '),
                1,
                40)),
                11,
                ' ') remarkTxt,
                LPAD(TRIM(m.order_call_key),
                40,
                ' ') orderCallKey,
                NVL(call_parent,
                0) call_parent,
                LPAD(a.parent,
                40,
                ' ') rel_key,
                d.order_key order_key,
                RPAD(m.prty_no,
                38,
                ' ') prty_no,
                RPAD(m.call_id,
                10,
                ' ') call_id,
                TRIM(RPAD(m.acc_cd,
                4,
                ' '))||'/'||TRIM(RPAD(m.acc_pos_cd,
                5,
                ' '))||'/'|| RPAD(DECODE(m.work_loc_cd,
                '..',
                '',
                '...',
                '',
                m.work_loc_cd),
                3,
                ' ') acc_pos_wl,
                RPAD(TO_CHAR(m.call_init_ts,
                'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),
                20,
                ' ') call_init_ts,
                m.opr_no opr_no,
                m.opr_step_no opr_step_no 
            FROM
                owi_order d,
                order_call m,
                related_call_query a 
            WHERE
                m.order_key=d.order_key 
                AND a.ord = d.order_key 
                AND m.order_call_key = a.call 
                AND m.init_callbrd_action_cd <> 'WIP') SELECT
                RPAD(LPAD(' ',
                (level - 1) * 2) || orderRecordIdTemp,
                32,
                ' ') orderRecordId,
                accPosWl,
                lineNumber,
                callIdVal,
                orderHldInd,
                prtyNo,
                callInitTs,
                callAction,
                ecdVal,
                remarkTxt,
                orderCallKey 
            from
                temp_rslt CONNECT 
            BY
                PRIOR orderCallKey = call_parent 
                AND PRIOR Order_key = rel_key START WITH orderCallKey IN (SELECT
                    b.orderCallKey 
                FROM
                    temp_rslt b 
                WHERE
                    NOT EXISTS (SELECT
                        'X' 
                    FROM
                        temp_rslt v 
                    WHERE
                        v.order_key = b.rel_key) 
                    AND (SELECT
                        COUNT(g.orderCallKey) 
                    from
                        temp_rslt g 
                    WHERE
                        g.orderCallKey = b.orderCallKey) = 1)  
                ORDER SIBLINGS BY
                    prtyNo,
                    callInitTs,
                    orderRecordIdTemp,
                    callIdVal,
                    orderCallKey
```

Edit 1: Added code tags !

Comment: Please format your question more friendly. Use an editor which match the parenthesis, e.g. `emacs`, to inspect your very long query. Your first char is a `(` but the last one is not `)`

Comment: I have added code tags to make it more readable. I added the closing parenthesis and still end up getting the same error !

Comment: Use and editor able to match parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

@user2392549 : download and use SQLDeveloper from the Oracle site. Its a freeware and provides a good formatting option with various styles. The query needs be formatted properly and then debugged for the missing parenthesis. Also, SQL Developer gives you the advantage of indicating the line number where the issue is occuring during typo or execution.

Download link : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html